# ASP.NET relative path is wrong in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am using relative paths in my ASP.NET project, because I am using friendly URLs.

For instance, I am pointing to my pages like this: "/myPage.aspx".

When I implement this on my web server it's working well, but when I debug it in Visual Studio, it's linking like this:

```
http://localhost:xxxx/myPage.aspx (which obviously doesn't exist)
```

Instead of this:

```
http://localhost:xxxx/MyProjectName/myPage.aspx
```

It seems like Visual Studio is going all the way up until the Visual Studio folder, instead of stopping at the project's folder name.

How can I resolve this in Visual Studio? I think there should be something in the Solution's Property page, but I am not finding it. I am using Visual Studio 2010.

I prefer to debug in Visual Studio instead of IIS. I know how to make this work in IIS.

Comment: My guess would be that Visual Studio is creating a virtual directory on the web server?  Is Visual Studio using IIS for debugging?  How are you creating this path in your code, and how is this affecting the application?  If all paths are relative then it shouldn't matter if the application is in a virtual directory or not.

Comment: VS opens a port at random and sometimes you don't need a project name! You can create a vpath in IIS or 
In vs2010, Right click your project and choose Properties!
There you can set your devserver instead of IIS and you can also set the MyProjectName as well!

Comment: @AdaBell'hMonTrésor That's great. Please post this as an answer so I accept it :) It's working now Thank You! Please mention in your answer that you'll have to set the Virtual Path to "/". This way the root will always point to the project's root folder.

Comment: okay tank you! A Nice Hat Off to you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio opens a port at random and sometimes you don't need a project name! You can create a vpath in IIS or in Visual Studio 2010, right click your project and choose Properties! There you can set your development server instead of IIS, and you can also set the MyProjectName as well!

Note: you'll have to set the Virtual Path to "/". This way the root will always point to the project's root folder.